# Issue with Using Polymorphism While Only Child Class has a Virtual Method

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the following code violate the C++11 standard in any way? I get a failed assertion in VC++ 2013.

```
class P {};

class C : public P
{
public:
    virtual void a() {}
};

int main()
{
    P* p = new C();
    delete p;
}
```

---

The failed assertion is:

```
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,

```
delete p;
```

has Undefined Behavior since the dynamic type of the pointee is different from the statically known type, and the latter doesn't have a virtual destructor.

C++11 §5.3.5/3:

> **”** In the first alternative (*delete object*), if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its
>   dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the
>   static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined

Comment: So he is only missing the virtual destructor?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Thanks a lot!!!
If that's the case - it's a shame that not all destructors are automatically virtual (I guess it's a performance thing...).

Comment: @Ofer: With an ordinary v-table based C++ implementation having destructors automatically virtual would increase the0 minimum size of class `P` from 1 byte to the size of a pointer, and would prevent the Empty Base class Optimization for class `P` as base. So yes it's in part a performance thing. But also a C compatibility and control thing: with automatically virtual destructor (and still talking about a conventional implementation) simple C struct declarations would not give the same memory layout in C and C++.